# RaspberryPi > Arduino (USB/serial comm issues)

Tags: php, ajax, arduino, raspberry-pi3, serial-communication

I have an issue with my current project (not that great with RPi stuff.. better with Arduino)

Summary: RPi has LAMP installed and is hosted a website. The webpage submits custom serial data via PHP to the USB connected Arduino, via ttyUSB0.  (This is an old project, and recently changed the Arduino, things used to be ttyACM0)

After going through and updating what I could find to: ttyUSB0..

I found that every time I sent serial data to the Arduino (it would reboot, and start its initial bootup homing routine).

- not sure if this can/should be fixed with just a capacitor on the reset line?

** When I added this line: `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -hupcl`

The Arduino rebooted again.. but then, after that, it was taking my page submissions/incoming serial data without issue.

Q1: Is there a way to get this line to permanently run/stick? `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -hupcl`

Update: question #2 removed  (was my mistake I was outputting Serial.print() that was triggering the fail response in my AJAX call)

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody answered.  My current 'solution' was to just physically place a capacitor on the GND/RESET I/O pins on the Arduino.   (would have much rather preferred a software/code solution though)  :(